# Uncaught typeError : (//some function) not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react class and I am calling getData function from the Store

```
class A extends React.component {
  componentDidMount(){
    Store.getData(a).then(data =>{
      //some data
    });
  }

  render (){
    //some data
  }
}
```

And the function in the Store is

```
getData : function (a) {
  return (a+b);
}
```

when I run I get an error

`Uncaught TypeError: Store.getData(a).then is not a function`
How do I rectify it ?

Comment: Please don't try to format the code in your questions using `<br>` elements - just type it normally and then use the `{}` button on the edit toolbar to format it as code.

Answer (score 2):

Function `then` is used to handle resolved [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). In your code function `getData` simply returns result of `a+b` (i.e. no promises are used). If you want to use `then` for some other operations you should update `getData` function so it uses promises, although in your case it is not clear why you could not use the result of function immediatelly.

Here is how you could use promise:

```
getData : function (a) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(a + b);
    });
}
```

However your function `getData` is not asynchronous so instead you could simply use the result of function `getData` directly in your class constructor:

```
class A extends React.component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var yourData = Store.getData(a);
        // do what you need with this data
    }
    // the rest of your class
}
```

Comment: Note: The 1st snippet could use [`return Promise.resolve(a + b);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

Comment: its a very big code and I have simplified it and posted the question. What are other options instead of .then ? I want to use the data coming from the getData method and use it further

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks for the tip, I didn't know you can use `Promise.resolve` directly

Comment: @user17422 Just like I showed in my second code sample, you can simply retrieve the data in constructor (or any other method) and use it where it is needed.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined I got this error after using Promise.resolve